# Sending a double (float) value in body of http post

Tags: flutter, http, post, error-handling, fastapi

Good day, day savers! 
I am using FastAPI along with flutter to make calls from an app to store certain data that can be the "double" type of data into the database.
This works by having the app send a http.post request with a double value to the api like this: \

```
Future MakeSaisirEspeceCall(String libelle, double montant) async {
    Uri url = Uri.parse('http://$ip/saisie_espece?libelle=$libelle&mode=1');
    http.Response response = await http.post(url, body: {"montant": montant});
    return response;
  }
```

Unfortunately, when I put any kind of data other than String, I get the following error: \

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast
#0      CastMap.forEach.<anonymous closure> (dart:_internal/cast.dart:288:25)
#1      _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:579:13)
#2      CastMap.forEach (dart:_internal/cast.dart:287:13)
#3      mapToQuery (package:http/src/utils.dart:17:7)
#4      Request.bodyFields= (package:http/src/request.dart:137:12)
#5      BaseClient._sendUnstreamed (package:http/src/base_client.dart:87:17)
#6      BaseClient.post (package:http/src/base_client.dart:32:7)
#7      post.<anonymous closure> (package:http/http.dart:69:16)
#8      _withClient (package:http/http.dart:164:20)
#9      post (package:http/http.dart:68:5)
#10     NetworkHelper.MakeSaisirEspeceCall (package:windows_test/networking/api_calls.dart:61:41)
#11     _SaisirEspeceState.EnterEspeceBons (package:windows_test/screens/saisir_espece.dart:240:44)
#12     _SaisirEspeceState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:windows_test/screens/saisir_espece.dart:225:27)
#13     _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1005:21)
#14     GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:198:24)
#15     TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:613:11)
#16     BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:298:5)
#17     BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:232:7)
#18     PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:563:9)
#19     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:94:12)
#20     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:139:9)
#21     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:579:13)
#22     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:137:18)
#23     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:123:7)
#24     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:445:19)
#25     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:425:22)
#26     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:326:11)
#27     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:380:7)
#28     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:344:5)
#29     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:302:7)
#30     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:285:7)
#31     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1442:13)
#32     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1335:19)
#33     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1244:7)
#34     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:170:10)
#35     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:331:7)
#36     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:94:31)
```

My api needs and requires a double/float value to operate correctly, since it needs it for calculations later.
What is the solution to this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try to convert `montant` to String

```
http.Response response = await http.post(url, body: {"montant": '$montant'});
```

Comment: That was my solution at first, but the issue is, the API expects a double value, not String.
It needs a double value so that it can use it for calculations.
If there is no other way to send the double data, should I just send it as String, then convert the String back to double in the API instead?

Comment: @Dr.Shower That's what you should do.

Comment: Use JSON as your exchange format instead of regular POST and you can get proper typing (for the types JSON understands). Using regular form variables there is no other valid type than string. In FastAPI this would be `Body` instead of `Form` as the source.

Comment: Could you please give an example on how to do that, I tried looking it up but all I find is POST methods along with String values. I really appreciate the help!